# How to turn off gray part auto completion in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios-simulator

[image]

I set all keyboard setting to off.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `UITextField` you can set their *property* `autocorrectionType` like so:

`textfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;`

OR in Storyboards:
[image]